Hidden element not remaining hidden with uBlock Origin?
I have this form element that I would like to hide, so that it is not shown on the web page, I am able to hide it with this line:
www.sakugabooru.com###reply-267797 > form

But when I visit another page of the website, it is shown again. The pages are essentially the same, it's one of those sites where each article has the same page, the only difference being the user comments under the article, here is an example below. The element I wish to keep hidden is highlited in red.


Look closer at your filters. The element IDs are not the same on each page – they include the post number as part of the ID attribute.
You need to either use a substring match for the ID attribute, e.g. div[id^="reply-"], or match another parent element such as #comments, or match some attributes of the form directly without relying on any parent matches, e.g. form[action="/comment/create"].
(All of these use the same syntax as CSS selectors.)
www.sakugabooru.com###comments form
www.sakugabooru.com##div[id^="reply-"] > form
www.sakugabooru.com##form[action="/comment/create"]`

